# Cannot get "images" net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (Gitpod)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, next.js, gitpod

On **Gitpod**, **my NextJS frontend** is trying to fetch the list of objects which contain **"product names"**, **"prices"** and **"images"** from **my Django Rest API backend**. Then, **my NextJS frontend** can get the list of objects which contain **"product names"** and **"prices"** but not **"images"** so **my NextJS frontend** cannot get only **"images"** as shown below:

(**"product names" such as "boots 4", "boots 3" ...** and **"prices" such as "£12.10", "£10.50" ...** are displayed but not **"images"**)

[image]

This is my desired output with **"product names"**, **"prices"** and **"images"**:

[image]

On **Gitpod**, both **my NextJS frontend on port 3000 open (private)** and **my Django Rest API backend on port 8000 open (private)** are running:

[image]

And **my NextJS frontend** uses this Rest API call with **"localhost"** as shown below to get the list of objects which contain **"product names"**, **"prices"** and **"images"**:

```
http://localhost:8000/api
```

And, there are these errors:

> 3000-gitpodio-templatetypescr-tqzkjl97w1d.ws-us33.gitpod.io/:987
> GET http://localhost:8000/media/images/paid.png
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> 3000-gitpodio-templatetypescr-tqzkjl97w1d.ws-us33.gitpod.io/:987
> GET http://localhost:8000/media/images/size.png
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> 3000-gitpodio-templatetypescr-tqzkjl97w1d.ws-us33.gitpod.io/:987
> GET http://localhost:8000/media/images/download.jpg
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> 3000-gitpodio-templatetypescr-tqzkjl97w1d.ws-us33.gitpod.io/:987
> GET http://localhost:8000/media/images/02173_l.jpg
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Actually, I solved these errors above by using this Rest API call with **my Gitpod domain** as shown below to get the list of objects:

```
https://8000-gitpodio-templatetypescr-tqzkjl97w1d.ws-us33.gitpod.io/api
```

But other error occurs as shown below:

```
Server Error
FetchError: invalid json response body at https://8000-gitpodio-templatetypescr-tqzkjl97w1d.ws-us33.gitpod.io/api reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
pages/index.js (73:16) @ async getStaticProps

  71 | export async function getStaticProps() {
  72 |   const res = await fetch("https://8000-gitpodio-templatetypescr-tqzkjl97w1d.ws-us33.gitpod.io/api");
> 73 |   const posts = await res.json();
     |                ^
  74 | 
  75 |   // const ress = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/");
  76 |   // const categories = await ress.json();
```

Actually, this Rest API call with **my Gitpod domain** is correct because with this Rest API call, I can get the list of objects on **Postman** from **my Django Rest API backend** on **Gitpod**:

```
https://8000-gitpodio-templatetypescr-tqzkjl97w1d.ws-us33.gitpod.io/api
```

Are there any solutions to solve this error and get the list of objects which contain **"product names"**, **"prices"** and **"images"**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make **the port 8000 for your Django Rest API backend "public"** to get the list of objects which contain **"product names"**, **"prices"** and **"images"**:

[image]

Finally, you can get the list of objects which contain **"product names"**, **"prices"** and **"images"**:

[image]